# jQuery animate horizontal stretch left issues

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-animate, stretch

I'm trying to stretch a div aligned to the right side of the page from 30px to 100% of page width. My javascript is moving a 30px bar across the page.. wrong :(

Thank you!

HTML:

```
 <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
                <h1>DEETRA</h1>
            </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
            <div id="trigger_left">
                <img class="arrow_small" id="main_arrow" src="images/left_small.png" alt="slide menu out" />
        </div>
            <div id="trigger_right">
                <img class="arrow_small" id="main_arrow" src="images/right_small.png" alt="slide menu in" />
            </div>
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="trans" id="overlay"></div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="main_nav">
                <div class="nav" style="float:left;">
                                <h3>CAMPAIGNS</h3>
                                <p>Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus.</p>
                        </div>
                            <div class="nav" style="float:right;">
                                <h3>CONTACT</h3>
                                <p>Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus.</p>
                        </div>
                            <div class="nav" style="margin:0 auto;">
                             <h3>COLLECTIONS</h3>
                             <p>Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus.</p>
                        </div>
                       </div>
            </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin:0;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(../images/one.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:FuturaStdLight, Futura, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:120%;
}
.trans {
    background-color:#000;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity:0.70;
    -khtml-opacity:0.70;
    opacity:0.70;
}
#logo {
    width:213px;
    height:105px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-indent:9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#main {
    width:100%;
    height:306px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-153px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#trigger_left {
    width:30px;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#trigger_right {
    width:30px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.arrow_small {
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-6px;
    margin-top:-12px;
    position:absolute;
}
#slider {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
}
#overlay {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    position:absolute;
}
#content {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#main_nav {
    width:744px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
.nav{
    width:208px;
    padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#footer {
    height:12px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0px 40px 40px 0px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Hide functions
    $('#slider').css({width: '30px'});
// Navigation drop down menu
    $('#trigger_left').click(function (){
        $('#slider').animate({ width: '100%' }, 1500 );
    });
    $('#trigger_right').click(function (){
        $('#slider').animate({ width: '30px',}, 1500 );
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel, I put your question into a jsfiddle, changed the images to blue `div`s, and put a border around your `#slider` so I could see what it was doing.

if I understand your question correctly, your code does exactly what you want it to.  Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/nn4sJ/3/

Comment: wow.. that's really odd. definitely works on jsfiddle but not in my code. maybe i've got some conflicting code elsewhere in the HTML and CSS. i'm going to edit this with the rest of the page. i've been having a lot of difficulty with absolute and relative positioning combined with z-index. the page is fluid like a flash site. anyway... i appreciate the help. let's see if this changes it.

Comment: works in jfiddle in chrome.. works in safari, awkwardly works in firefox.. does not work in chrome locally or hosted. is jfiddle magic?

Comment: update.. does not work in safari. both it and chrome are moving the 30px bar instead of stretching the entire div.

Answer (score 0):

Changed some css, now it works. Used width:100% instead of inherited.

```
#slider {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    float:right;
    position:absolute;
}
#overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Daniel, if you don't accept the answers of people helping you, or at least up-vote them, you'll find that people my stop helping you...we're in it for the rep.  ;o)

Comment: I didn't notice that you were using `inherit`.  I'd venture to say that 9 times out of 10 `inherit` is not what you want.